# Google アナリティクスのSDK、APIについて

Tags: google-analytics-api

お世話になっております。
Google アナリティクスの機能として、下記廃止の記載を確認させて頂きました。

[Google アナリティクス開発者サービス SDK の終了](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9167112?hl=ja)

> - これらのプロパティに関するデータの収集と処理は、2019 年 10 月 31 日に停止します。
> - これらのプロパティの過去のデータに関するレポートについては、2020 年 1 月 31 日まで Google アナリティクスの管理画面と API 経由で引き続きアクセスできます。
> - Google アナリティクス開発者サービス SDK のサポートがすべて終了すると、Google アナリティクスの管理画面でも API 経由でも、かかるプロパティにアクセスすることはできなくなり、 それらのデータは Google アナリティクス サーバーから削除されます。
>
> この件につきましては、その時期が近づいた時点で改めて通知いたします。

【質問】
今現状、Android、iOSにおいてGoogle アナリティクスのSDK、APIを使用しております。
上記の内容に伴い、その使用しているSDKのプログラムを削除してない場合、APIの動作はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「そのままプログラム変更しなくてもエラーで落ちないのか、もしくは必ずプログラム変更をしなければいけないものなのか」これは、プログラムの中身を見ないと誰にも分かりません。例外をどうハンドルしているか、情報が必要です。

Comment: ※追記
こちらのプログラムでは、例外のハンドリングは行っておりません。
GoogleAnalyticsのAPI側で上記のように期限が切れた場合、どのようになるのか、どのような値が返却されるのかが知りたいです。

Comment: コメントの追記によって質問の内容が変わっています。あなたのプログラムがエラーになるかどうかという点は質問からは削除し、単純に「APIの動作がどうなるか」という質問に変えましょう。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます。